# Is this sql vulnerability in my code?

Tags: asp.net

Is this sql vulnerability in my code?Because I have Parameterized the SQL ,so no sql Injection? anyone give some suggests will appreciate!If yes, How to repair?

ASP.NET CODE:

```
   public DataTable CompanySearchUser(int pageSize, int currentPage, string whereCondition)
        {
            DbParameter[] parms = {
                                       DbHelper.MakeInParam("@PageSize",(DbType)SqlDbType.Int,4,pageSize),
                                       DbHelper.MakeInParam("@PageNumber",(DbType)SqlDbType.Int,4,currentPage),
                                       DbHelper.MakeInParam("@where",(DbType)SqlDbType.NVarChar,500,whereCondition)
                                   };
            DataTable userlist = DbHelper.ExecuteDataset(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "spCompanySearchUser", parms).Tables[0];

            return userlist;

        }
```

SQL CODE:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spCompanySearchUser]
                                      @PageSize   INT
                                      @PageNumber INT,
                                      @where nvarchar(550)--like 'and a=1 '

AS
  DECLARE @RowStart INT
  DECLARE @RowEnd INT
  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
  IF @PageNumber > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @PageNumber = @PageNumber - 1
        SET @RowStart = @PageSize * @PageNumber + 1;
        SET @RowEnd = @RowStart + @PageSize - 1;
        SET @SQL='
        WITH AllUsers
             AS (SELECT 
       UB.UserBaicInfoID,
       UB.UserName,
       UB.HighestEducation,
       UB.Age,
       UB.Sex,
       UB.WorkExperience,
       UB.PositionDesired,
       UB.UpdateTime,
                        Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY UB.UpdateTime DESC) AS RowNumber             
       From  UserBasicInfo UB
         WHERE ResumeState=1 '+@where+')

   SELECT * FROM  AllUsers WHERE  RowNumber >=' + Str(@RowStart) + '  AND RowNumber <= ' + Str(@RowEnd) + ''
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
    END
```

Is this sql vulnerability in my code?Because I have Parameterized the SQL ,so no sql Injection? anyone give some suggests will appreciate!If yes, How to repair?

Comment: do not pass the whole `where` condition (or even a part of it verbatim). construct the expression yourself from the passed parameters. check parameters and make sure that they are of expected types before pasting them in to the query.

Answer (score 0):

cannot test it right now but i would say yes it is.

you pass in @where and you do a concatenation, your @where is doing actual sql code not a real "where" clause

then you do a exec on the final sql code

this can be exploited

not sure what your whereCondition look like but try this

```
    public DataTable CompanySearchUser(int pageSize, int currentPage, string whereCondition)
    {

        /**** add this  to test ****/

        whereCondition += " or 1=1";

        /**** add this  to test ****/


        DbParameter[] parms = {
                                   DbHelper.MakeInParam("@PageSize",(DbType)SqlDbType.Int,4,pageSize),
                                   DbHelper.MakeInParam("@PageNumber",(DbType)SqlDbType.Int,4,currentPage),
                                   DbHelper.MakeInParam("@where",(DbType)SqlDbType.NVarChar,500,whereCondition)
                               };
        DataTable userlist = DbHelper.ExecuteDataset(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "spCompanySearchUser", parms).Tables[0];

        return userlist;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's still insecure and non-performant.

You should just do the SQL dynamically and add the parameters there rather than relying on sp_executeSQL.

Building the string with the `@` placeholder items `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@placeholder", value)` values, then adding those parameters, will generally be better, more secure, more manageable, and won't waste SQL's time since it won't be able to optimize your statements.

You may actually get better performance doing it dynamically in code rather that in a stored proc since SQL will cache every one of those statements and re-execute them if an identical statement comes along.